# Qr code can't identify

Tags: qr-code, zxing

[image]

I have a picture qr code, want to long press to identify this qr code picture, but can't identify, excuse me what reason, is the qr code picture is there a problem?

Comment: The qr code seems correct; as per the [zxing decoder](https://zxing.org/w/decode?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2F6hLIb.png); so the problem is likely with your code.

Comment: You need to show your Java code to get answers what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to say you cant decode the QRcode then heres your solution.
if your trying to say somthing else then im sorry for my off topic solution

as Burhan Khalid said the code is valid, but your your code is missing a border.
the border (or quiet zone) helps separate the QRcode from your content.

heres my test
im going to use https://webqr.com/index.html for decoding.
i uploaded it to the web site and it didn't decode.
i then opened it in [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) and gave it a border of 25 pixels, i then saved and uploaded the new code to the website and it decoded successfully

heres your qr code with 25px quiet zone, 
[image: here is your qr code with 25px border]

heres the structure of a QRcode 
[image: heres a picture showing the qr code structure]
Source [the wikipedia article on QR codes, subsection Standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Standards)